# Physicalism: If consciousness isn't an illusion, what's its nature? What are the best clues?

Tags: consciousness, psychology, physicalism

I'm asking very generally so I'm expecting very general answers. I've read the answers from the question: [How can consciousness be an illusion?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37672/how-can-consciousness-be-an-illusion) and I pretty much got understanding of how our brain could create the illusion of consciousness.

From what I've read, I got the impression that the "illusion model" isn't what most modern materialists (or *[physicalists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physicalism)*) consider true. I know there isn't much empirical research on the topic, but I am looking for any attempts to explain consciousness without human psychology involved, i.e. models that explain consciousness as a physical phenomenon.

The question suggested as duplicate is a nice example of the models I'm asking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does materialism presuppose that a self is a bundle of mental states and perceptions?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31783/does-materialism-presuppose-that-a-self-is-a-bundle-of-mental-states-and-percept)

Comment: @AlexanderSKing Thanks for the link, though I think it's actually quite far from what I've asking.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing I see this answer could one of the models I'm asking for. Though, this kind of theorizing seems kind of too abstract to actually help me deeper understand the problem of consciousness.